# Program received signal 0 for uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app where user can take picture from camera and image is displayed in imageview.
It works fine for the first time but the second time app is crashed leaving memory warning level=1

I google around and tried all possible ways but no use

Below is the code i used in my app

```
       UIImagePickerController *imgpicker;

        @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController *imgpicker;



        @synthesize imgpicker;  

        if(actionSheet.tag==1)
            {
                NSLog(@"button index:%i",buttonIndex);
                if(buttonIndex == 0)
                { NSLog(@"button index for camera:%i",buttonIndex);
                    if(self.imgpicker==nil){
                    self.imgpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

                    self.imgpicker.delegate =self;
                    self.imgpicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

                    }

                    [self presentModalViewController:self.imgpicker animated:YES];


                    [imgpicker release];
                    return;

                }
}

        - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
        {
           NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo editing info:%@",info);
            UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];



            imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 75, 75)];



                NSData *newjpg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);



            [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:newjpg]];



            [scrollView addSubview:imageview];



            [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

            [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
self.imgpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
```

to this:

```
self.imgpicker=[[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

and remove this line:

```
[imgpicker release];
```

If you're showing the image picker more than once, you're leaking memory from the image view that gets allocated every time the picker finishes.
You're also adding the image view to the scroll view and the scroll view to the view controller's view every time. You just need to do it once, and the update the `image` property on the image view.

Try this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo editing info:%@",info);
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    if (imageview == nil) {
        imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 75, 75)];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageview];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    }

    NSData *newjpg = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:newjpg]];

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @mortenfast: I tried your code but the same issue persist. Actually, the scenario is, i have tableview when i click on one of the table cell a view with image view and one button is pushed. When i click on button i get an action sheet with "Take Photo","PhotoLibrary" and "Cancel" button. I capture a image from camera and display it in image view and come back to tableview and if i go for other cell and capture image from camera app gets crashed

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the crash log?

Comment: No stack trace, even i don't find crash report, just a message "Program received signal 0"

Comment: Here is the crash report:Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xac001311

Comment: If you run this as a debug build in the simulator with breakpoints enabled, you should see the stack trace in the break point navigator when the crash occurs.

Comment: crash occurs on device with camera source,works fine in simulator

Comment: OK, run a debug build on the device from Xcode with break points enabled. It's the stack trace that will tell you where the crash is. Your app is referencing memory it's not owning, and it's important to find out where it does this. It could be code that's executed in the picker view's parent controller. Only the stack trace can tell.

Comment: when i click a 'use' button of camera source app crashes

Comment: Is the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method called right before the crash?

Comment: For the first time it is called and second time controls jumps from imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: to viewWillAppear

Comment: So the crash is probably caused by some code in the picker's parent view controller. What does the `viewWillAppear:` method in the parent view controller do?

Comment: @mortenfast:In imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; is not called for second time

Answer (score 0):

Please create UIImagePickerController object in your AppDelegate class and initialize in your AppDidFinishloading method : didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Realese it on appDelegate dealloc method.
You can access it in your needed view controller Page from appdelegate class.
Please do not create evertytime UIImagePickerController object when u needed and realese it.

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

App Delegate 
// .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyProjectAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIImagePickerController *image_picker;

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *image_picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

-(void)initializeImagePickerView;

@end
```

// .m

```
#import "MyProjectAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation MyProjectAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController,image_picker;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self initializeImagePickerView];

    // Set the navigation controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void)initializeImagePickerView
{
    // Picker View
    self.image_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.image_picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [image_picker release];
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

//RootView Controller
// .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyProjectAppDelegate.h"

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>{

    MyProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}
-(IBAction)btnPhotoPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

// .m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (MyProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

-(IBAction)btnPhotoPressed:(id)sender
{
    appDelegate.image_picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    appDelegate.image_picker.delegate=self;
    [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.image_picker animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark UIImagePickerController delegate
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *imgCapturePhoto = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // You can use image here

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This will definitely help u.

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, i tried but the same issue persists. i have a device with version 4.0 which was jailbroken. Is it work?